# Returned value not expected - closures

Tags: javascript, function, closures, return-value

I don't understand why it returns 0, it is supposed to increment by 1, is there something I don't know about closures?

```
 let i = 0;
    const getRenderValue = function() {

      return i++;
    };
    const Component = function() {
      let hello = getRenderValue();
      console.log(hello); // return 0, expected value 1
    };
    Component();
```

Comment: i++ increments i after i is returned. Use ++i  if you want it pre-incremented.

Comment: Thanks, I felt like a newbie, I thought it had to do with the closure itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your closure does increment the value of `i` by one. If you did `console.log(i);` instead of `console.log(hello);`, you'd be seeing `1` on screen as expected.

Your closure however returns the value of `i` **prior** to the increment as it returns `i++`: It is a property of the postfix increment `i++` that it returns `i` before and not after the increment. Use the prefix increment `++i` if you want to return the changed value.

Comment: Yea, I already did as you told me, I thought I had to see how the closure as such.